# Nested brackets empty loop explanation

Tags: python

What is the value of `x` after the following code is executed?

```
x = []
for i in range(3):
    x = [x + x]

A.[[[[]]]].
B.[[[],[]]].
C.[[[[],[]],[[],[]]]].
D.[[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

The answer is *c*, can someone explain why this happens? I understand the 2/3 iteration, but don't understand how it went from 1st to 2nd, as in why it didn't become `[[],[]]`

Comment: print x in loop to know why

Comment: Would you consider renaming your question so that it's a bit more specific? I think it will help fellow SO users who are searching for the same issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used extra spaces for a clear expression.

**First Run** :

`x + x = [] + [] = []`
*empty list + empty list is another empty list*

so `[x + x] = [ [] ]`
*attention! `[[]]` is not an empty list, it is a list containing an empty list*

**Second Run**:

`x + x = [[]] + [[]] = [[], []]`
so `[x + x] = [ [[], []] ]`

**Third Run** :

`x + x = [[[], []]] + [[[], []]] = [[[[], []]], [[[], []]]]`

so `[x + x] = [ [[[[], []]], [[[], []]]] ]`

Comment: you are right! I'll rearrange it. Sorry for that, it is my first post...

Answer (score 7):

```
x = []
for i in range(3):
    print('\ni =', i)
    print('x =' , x)
    print('x + x =', x + x)
    print('[x + x] =', [x + x])
    x = [x + x]
```

**output:**

```
i = 0
x = []
x + x = []  # Here is why. If you extend [] by [], you get []. 
[x + x] = [[]]  # And we wrap the result.

i = 1
x = [[]]
x + x = [[], []]
[x + x] = [[[], []]]

i = 2
x = [[[], []]]
x + x = [[[], []], [[], []]]
[x + x] = [[[[], []], [[], []]]]
```

Comment: ooooooh okay thanks, not sure why i was having trouble. thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Lets step through the code, shall we?:

- `x = []`: Create a empty list called `x`
- `for i in range(3)`: repeat the code below three times:

  - `x = [x + x]` reassign the value of `x` to the current value of `x`, plus the current value of `x` and wrap that in a list.

Essentially, what is happening each iteration is that your list is nested by one level, and the list inside your list currently become sub list of that nested list.

In layman's terms, the simplest explantion would be - *On each iteration of the for loop, the value of the variable x is reassigned to the value of two nested, which can also contain two other nested list, inside a single list*.

Here is an illustration to show the value of x on each iteration of the `for`-loop:

```
>>> # x is empty
>>> x = []
>>> 
>>> # 1st iteration
>>> x = [x + x]
>>> # x
>>> x
[[]] # your list is nested by one level
>>> 
>>> # 2nd iteration
>>> x = [x + x]
>>> # x
>>> x
[[[], []]] # your list is nested by three levels
>>> # 3rd iteration
>>> x = [x + x]
>>> # x
>>> x
[[[[], []], [[], []]]] # your list is nested by four levels
>>>
```

If the above illustration is too crowded, here is a shorter one:

```
First iteration
Value of x: [[]] 

Second iteration
Value of x: [[[], []]] 

Third iteration
Value of x: [[[[], []], [[], []]]]
```

I also find creating a tree like structure from nested list, helps to understand what is happening better:

```
[ # 1st level
    [ # second level
        [ # third level
            [], # fourth level
            [] 
        ], 
        [
            [], 
            [] # fourth level
        ] # third level
    ] # second level
] # 1st level
```